# How to prove an inequality that sum of variables is larger or equal than sum of squares?

Tags: inequality

How one can prove that if $x,y,z>0$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=3$ then $x+y+z\geq (xy)^2+(yz)^2+(zx)^2$? I tried AM-GM but without success.